# Passing multiple checkbox values & dyamically generating textboxes based on checkboxes checked in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

Using - ASP.NET MVC 4

UI is like -

```
Select      Product Code      Product Name

Checkbox    Product 1         Apple
Checkbox    Product 2         Banana
Checkbox    Product 3         Grapes

Submit Button
```

On submit button click i need to validate whether checkbox selected or not. If not, shows message - Please select one product.

If selected, then in the controller, pass the selected Product Code & Name & no. of checkboxes checked to another page

How can we achieve this in MVC 4?

Comment: Also it can be multiple values that can be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `@Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Checkbox, "Product 1")` is assigning `"Product 1"` as a html attribute and will render `<input length="9" type="checkbox" .../>` (the length attribute has been added with a value equal the number of characters in the text). Its also creating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes. And the `[Required]` attribute is pointless (a bool is either true or false and will always be required). Currently you have no relationship between the checkbox and product.

You should create a view model to represent what you want to display

```
public class ProductVM
{
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  List<ProductVM> model = new List<ProductVM>()
  {
    new ProductVM() { Code = "Product 1", Name = "Apple" },
    new ProductVM() { Code = "Product 2", Name = "Banana" },
    new ProductVM() { Code = "Product 3", Name = "Grapes"}
  };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<ProductVM> model)
{
  foreach(ProductVM item in model)
  {
    if (item.IsSelected)
    {
      string code = item.Code;
      string name= item.Name;
    }
  }
}
```

View

```
@model List<ProductVM>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Code)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor((m => m[i].IsSelected, Model[i].Name)
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

If you want client side validation, you are going to have to write your own validation attribute that implements `IClientValitable` and write the associated jquery validation methods (but that's the subject of a separate question)

Comment: but in the Edit action method, how can we get the checked checkbox value.

Comment: Sorry, the POST method should be `Edit(List<ProductVM> model)`, then all you need is a loop `foreach(ProductVM item in model) { if(item.IsSelected) { //do something`

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the modified properties. As far as redirecting to another page to edit the selected products, that's a separate issue and you need to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks..have raised new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398894/dyamically-generating-textboxes-based-on-checkboxes-checked-in-mvc-4

Comment: @DreamBig, Had a quick look (no time to answer right now). No point just repeating this question - it will only get voted down and closed. Explain what you have done so far and just address the issue of passing the selected values to another method for editing

Comment: If i don't select any checkbox then it is not validating

Comment: No, as I noted in my last paragraph. Its a big exercise to do this client side. You can of course check server side `if (!model.Any(m => m.IsSelected) { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please select one"); }` and return the view.

Comment: yes looking to do server side only. Also i am not able to add the checked values back in the model so that i can use them on the next page.

Comment: Also the validation message needs to show at the top of the page, so when adding @Html.ValidationMessageFor, it gives error as we need a list.